# I can make the mechanical energy 0 or in fact anything. Is this normal?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation, potential-energy, conventions

We let the rope fall with $\alpha = \pi/2$ (no initial velocity).

[image]

if I choose the original of potential energy as the picture indicates there, this means 
that:

$$E_m = E_{pe} + E_c = \frac12mv^2 + mgz + c\\ 
Ep(0)=0=mg\cdot0 + c \implies c=0$$
then $E_m(0) =  0 $ (initial velocity is 0) 
and $E_m$ is constant so it is always 0.

How can this be possible? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Energy is relative. You allow the potential energy to become negative (since you set it at zero at the top), so the sum of kinetic plus potential remains zero.

If you had set potential energy = 0 at the bottom of the trajectory, you would have had a constant positive energy at all time. You are not really "learning" anything about the energy of the rope - just that it's constant.